# Pinpoint location (latitude & longitude) in Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, location

I have data of a location's latitude and longitude. I want to display it into a map in my application. I planned to use Google Maps to display this location to user.

To do this, would I need the Google Maps API? or the Google Maps Coordinate? 
I've looked into their website, but all those varieties just makes me confused. 
I only need it to display the data (latitude and longitude) into visual (map) to make my application more user-friendly.

I have never used Google Maps API before, so for those that have experience in it, please guide me.

Google Maps API : http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/products/mapsapi.html#

Google Maps Coordinate: http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/products/coordinate.html?rd=1#

On a side note, I might sell the application (using subscription), so I would need the Google Maps API license. Anyone know how much it is and how is the procedure? (e.g., monthly or yearly basis, per user or per use, etc.)

**EDIT**

Or is there any other API for the mapping? something like Google Maps API.

Comment: [This](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) should help.

Comment: Yes, this looks like what I need. Marking the location based on the lat&long to be displayed to user. So this is using Google Maps API?

Comment: You might be able to just use the [Static Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) instead, if you simply want to display a map.

Comment: Does markers can be put into the static map? There will be lots of markers, and the markers will be dynamic.

Answer (score 3):

We have to give latitude and longitude .

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () {
        var mapOptions = {
            //give latitude and long
            center: new google.maps.LatLng("18.9750", "72.8258"),
            zoom: 8,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
            //give latitude and long
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng("18.9750", "72.8258");
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: "Mumbai"
        });
    }
</script>

<div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
```